Nuget dependencies are not copied to the target directory (net472 vs. net80)
I have a project that can be extended via plugins. The plugins are loaded via MEF, so there is no direct dependency from the EXE to the plugins.
The following image shows the Project dependencies. As you can see, there is no dependency from Executable to Plugin.

When I do a complete rebuild of the solution, all necessary dependencies for net472 are copied to the target directory, including Enums.NET.dll. For target platform net80 the dependencies are not copied.
As a consequence, the net472 build works as expected, whereas the net80 build does not find the Enums.NET.dll.
This is what the target directory for net80 looks like:

And this is how it looks at net472:

As you can see, the content differs significantly and therefore net80 does not work.
How can net80 be forced to copy all necessary DLL's into the target directory?
It is not caused by Enums.NET. The error also occurs with e.g. Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, but this is much larger and has further dependencies, which is why I did not use it for this example, because it only makes this sample unnecessarily complicated.
Context
CSPROJ of Executable:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;net80</TargetFrameworks>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Contracts\Contracts.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" Version="8.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

CSPROJ of Plugin:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;net80</TargetFrameworks>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Contracts\Contracts.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Enums.Net" Version="5.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="5.0.*" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" Version="8.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Solution explorer view:


How is your plugin being copied to your executable bin folder? In theory this shouldn't happen as part of the build, as your plugin does not have a direct dependency on the plugin.

@oscar Yes it is. As you can see from the target folder screenshots. You're right, if you only build it will not be copied - but if you do a complete rebuild it will be copied because all of the projects are build.

I wasn't disputing that it is, I was asking how that happens. Do you have a custom build action that copies the plugin across? The build wouldn't copy the DLL unless there is a dependency on the project. Do any files stick around if you clean the project

@oscar No there is no custom build action. If you perform a rebuild all it will build all projects in solution and the plugin is part of the solution. We changed the output directory of every project so that all projects are building to the same target directory. <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\$(Configuration)</OutputPath> does this trick - as you can see in the CSPROJ. That's part of all project files.

Try adding the following to your plugin .csproj under the property group.
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#copylocallockfileassemblies

Mostly. The requested Enums.NET.dll is now present in the target directory. But at runtime it can't be loaded. Could not load file or assembly 'Enums.NET, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7ea1c1650d506225'. The system cannot find the file specified. Any Ideas about that? Adding a custom AssemblyResolver will not be a valid solution.

Does it do that for both targets (i.e. net48 and net8.0)? Always tricky to debug those sorts of issues, may be worth running fusion log to see how it's trying to resolve the dependency - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer

Nope. That only occurs on net472. If I remove that build target from Executable I can debug net80 but it doesn't help much.

Okay, not sure why it can't load the assembly. Does running fusion log give any indicator why? Just run fusion log as admin, run your application and then refresh fusion log - it should show a log of why the assembly load failed, where it's looking for it., etc.

Sorry - I'm too stupid. I'm not able to run fusion log in a way that it produces any results. I did the setting changes and I also tried Fusion++ - no luck. It looks that both apps didn't recognize that there is an application running. Maybe it's because of net80 - no idea. Your job is done. Thx a lot.
